# Debugger for Chrome: cannot debug using Attach option

Tags: angularjs, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I want to debug my AngularJS / Typescript site using **"Attach"** option of Debugger for Chrome rather than "Launch" option that opens new browser windows each time.

Here is a launch.json file created for Debugger for Chrome:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I start Chrome by passing `--remote-debugging-port=9222` argument:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

I host the app using **serve**: serve -l 8080

But I cannot make the debugger to work, breakpoints don't get  hit, and VSCode doesnt seem to be able to Attach.

**Am I missing something? Thanks.**

[image]

Comment: try again with all chrome windows closed? Might have a window open with that port.